# How to turn off multithreading on Caffe for Visual Studio?

Tags: caffe

I'm trying to debug an issue that's causing a crash and the multithreading is complicating my troubleshooting.  How do I turn off multithreading for the Windows branch of Caffe in Visual Studio?

Comment: Multithread(on CPU) only happens in Data layer. So you can drop it in the net.prototxt and try "input" instead.

Comment: @DaleSong thanks.  Unfortunately I have to be taking in input from LMDB to reproduce the bug.

Comment: Maybe you can print some log to in the data layer to infer the bug.@empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of v1.0.1, `torch.set_num_threads(1)` covers everything, including the BLAS libraries.
I tested it on PyTorch 1.6 and Python 3.6 and it received a total of 3 threads (including 1 for Python).

source: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/16899